# To find the total number of components of a parallel system

Tags: probability-theory

A system consisting of n components functions iff atleast one of n components functions. Suppose that all the n components function independently, each with probability 3/4. If the probability of functioning of the system is 63/64 then find n.

As far I got into my thoughts is: this system is certainly a parallel system. If a1,a2,.....,an are n components of the system then union of them makes 63/64. How to find n??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability of failure is 1/64.  Failure means all components fail =$(1/4)^n$  Therefore n=3.

Comment: Oh! that way. Thanks@herb Steinberg.